# Using Android's MediaRouter to cast the device screen into firetv stick or a client app?

Tags: android, screen, amazon-fire-tv, mediarouter

I am trying to mirror cast using my own app into a Fire TV Stick that is connected to the televsion. It has an option to Mirror the display. My phone can connect to the Fire TV Stick this way, but I would like to mirror something with a smaller resolution and even if I change my phone's resolution using adb, I think it sends the native resolution anyway.
I looked into MediaRouter and MediaRouteProvider. Also downloaded the Media Router sample that it's snippets are used in the documentation. The sample ran but didn't work. And this API is super complex and have so many things in it. I am not sure how to build a simple app that cast video(and later phone's screen) into another device, either the Amazon Fire TV stick mirror display or at least into a client app I will also write.
I couldn't find compact enough samples to do what I want. Do you have any idea where there is a sample that works and is not a massive amount of code?

I couldn't make it work following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding something in the API to do the mircast for me, I was able to just read pixel data from the MediaProjection and VirtualDisplay and send that using sockets.
It wasn't easy, I had to use a GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES from the SurfaceTexture, render that into my own offscreen GL_TEXTURE2D and then read that using glReadPixels and the attached framebuffer.